# ggpairs fill histograms with white

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I would like to get the histograms or bar line in the following plot in white. It's mainly for ink saving concerns.

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
data(tips, package = "reshape")
pm <- ggpairs(tips[,1:3])
```

I've tried

```
pm + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),rect= element_rect(fill="white"))
```

but couldn't reach the histogram fill.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
ggpairs(tips[,1:3], params = c(fill = "white", color = "black")) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I must have a newer version of GGally. As it is throwing that `params` is depreciated and `wrap` should be used instead. Thanks for the lead

Comment: @DJJ I have the version available on CRAN. The new version seems to offer very complicated (and not well documented) way to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks I'm going for the CRAN one then.